# How to show qpx express in PHP

Tags: php, google-qpx-express-api

I am confused to show my code for qpx express API. I use qpx express free. Is it qpx express for showing real time flight schedule? I had written this code like this

```
<?php
$url = "https://www.googleapis.com/qpxExpress/v1/trips/search?key=myapikey";

$postData = '{
  "request": {
    "passengers": {
      "adultCount": 1
    },
    "slice": [
      {
        "origin": "BOS",
        "destination": "LAX",
        "date": "2016-03-05"
      },
      {
        "origin": "LAX",
        "destination": "BOS",
        "date": "2016-03-05"
      }
    ]
  }
}';

$curlConnection = curl_init();

curl_setopt($curlConnection, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/json"));
curl_setopt($curlConnection, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curlConnection, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
curl_setopt($curlConnection, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postData);
curl_setopt($curlConnection, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
curl_setopt($curlConnection, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curlConnection, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);

$results = curl_exec($curlConnection);
```

is that right code? And my goal is only showing flight schedule in my website. Any idea for that? I'll appreciate if you can help me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working, but need to request date not from the past. For example this code json will find some flights. You can use [this demo flight database](https://qpx-express-demo.itasoftware.com/) to check your json without submitting request to real QPX api:

```
{
  "request": {
    "passengers": {
      "adultCount": 1
    },
    "slice": [
      {
        "origin": "BOS",
        "destination": "LAX",
        "date": "2016-03-09"
      },
      {
        "origin": "LAX",
        "destination": "BOS",
        "date": "2016-03-09"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So I just using BOS-MUC for my query. First thing you have to do a right error reporting, so the dates should be not in the past. I just reading the tripOptions. For each TripOptions the slices in the query to the server and then the legs.

## One Segment

As response from the Server for the tripInfos. You have trips which are divided into the 2 slices requested. And for each slide you have a segment. One segment look like this.

```
"segment": [{
        "kind": "qpxexpress#segmentInfo",
        "duration": 175,
        "flight": {
            "carrier": "TK",
            "number": "1638"
        },
        "id": "GBPj1TVAITht-Rmq",
        "cabin": "COACH",
        "bookingCode": "Y",
        "bookingCodeCount": 9,
        "marriedSegmentGroup": "2",
        "leg": [{
            "kind": "qpxexpress#legInfo",
            "id": "Lp142e8MFu5oJvyK",
            "aircraft": "321",
            "arrivalTime": "2016-03-20T11:15+02:00",
            "departureTime": "2016-03-20T07:20+01:00",
            "origin": "MUC",
            "destination": "IST",
            "originTerminal": "1",
            "destinationTerminal": "I",
            "duration": 175,
            "mileage": 976,
            "meal": "Meal"
        }],
        "connectionDuration": 165
    }, {
        "kind": "qpxexpress#segmentInfo",
        "duration": 680,
        "flight": {
            "carrier": "TK",
            "number": "81"
        },
        "id": "GMi6-VxjbU+icJPl",
        "cabin": "COACH",
        "bookingCode": "Y",
        "bookingCodeCount": 5,
        "marriedSegmentGroup": "3",
        "leg": [{
            "kind": "qpxexpress#legInfo",
            "id": "LBkTIA9o3PxzqKDC",
            "aircraft": "330",
            "arrivalTime": "2016-03-20T19:20-04:00",
            "departureTime": "2016-03-20T14:00+02:00",
            "origin": "IST",
            "destination": "BOS",
            "originTerminal": "I",
            "destinationTerminal": "E",
            "duration": 680,
            "mileage": 4814,
            "meal": "Meal",
            "secure": true
        }]
    }]
```

## Code

So a segment of a slice. Is an array which has legs. To just get the flight info I used this code.

```
<?php
function getInformation($slices) {
    $url = "https://www.googleapis.com/qpxExpress/v1/trips/search?key=INSERTYOURAPIKEYHERE";

    $postData = '{
                "request": {
                    "passengers": {
                        "adultCount": 1
                        },
                    "slice": ' . json_encode($slices) . '
                }
            }';

    $curlConnection = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curlConnection, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/json"));
    curl_setopt($curlConnection, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($curlConnection, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
    curl_setopt($curlConnection, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postData);
    curl_setopt($curlConnection, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($curlConnection, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($curlConnection, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
    //$results = json_decode(curl_exec($curlConnection), true);
    if (isset($results['error'])) {
        var_dump($results);
        exit();
    }
    // i save the content to a file for better debugging
    //return json_decode(file_get_contents('BOSMUC.JSON'), true);
    return $results;
}

$slices = array(array('origin' => 'BOS', 'destination' => 'MUC', 'date' => "2016-03-16")
              , array('origin' => 'MUC', 'destination' => 'BOS', 'date' => "2016-03-20"));

$resultAsArray = getInformation($slices);

$trips = array_filter($resultAsArray['trips']['tripOption'], function($kind) {
        if (!isset($kind['kind'])) {
            return false;
        }
        if ($kind['kind'] == "qpxexpress#tripOption") {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    });


foreach ($trips as $trip) {
    echo "------- NEW FLIGHT ---------\n";
    echo "FLight Cost: " . $trip['saleTotal'] . "\n";
    foreach ($trip['slice'] as $index => $slice) {
        print "SLICE $index: " . $slices[$index]['origin'] . " TO " . $slices[$index]['destination'] . "\n";
        foreach ($slice['segment'] as $segment) {
            foreach ($segment['leg'] as $leg) {
                print "FROM " . $leg['origin'] . " to " . $leg['destination'] . " (" . $leg['departureTime'] . "-" . $leg['arrivalTime'] . ")" . "\n";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So this is just a beginning. But should be a good start. To get the code running you have to repace `INSERTYOURAPIKEYHERE` with your own api key.

## Output

```
------- NEW FLIGHT ---------
FLight Cost: USD5988.36
SLICE 0: BOS TO MUC
FROM BOS to MUC (2016-03-16T21:20-04:00-2016-03-17T09:40+01:00)
SLICE 1: MUC TO BOS
FROM MUC to BOS (2016-03-20T15:35+01:00-2016-03-20T19:35-04:00)
------- NEW FLIGHT ---------
FLight Cost: USD6020.66
SLICE 0: BOS TO MUC
FROM BOS to MUC (2016-03-16T21:20-04:00-2016-03-17T09:40+01:00)
SLICE 1: MUC TO BOS
FROM MUC to FRA (2016-03-20T09:00+01:00-2016-03-20T10:10+01:00)
FROM FRA to BOS (2016-03-20T10:55+01:00-2016-03-20T14:20-04:00)
------- NEW FLIGHT ---------
FLight Cost: USD12115.86
SLICE 0: BOS TO MUC
FROM BOS to LHR (2016-03-16T20:30-04:00-2016-03-17T07:20+00:00)
FROM LHR to MUC (2016-03-17T08:55+00:00-2016-03-17T11:50+01:00)
SLICE 1: MUC TO BOS
FROM MUC to LHR (2016-03-20T07:00+01:00-2016-03-20T08:05+00:00)
FROM LHR to BOS (2016-03-20T09:25+00:00-2016-03-20T13:09-04:00)
```

Just the last 3 Outputs.